# EF Fluent api poco genereting and mapping by using existing Db

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have 2  tables as shown below , I am confused about how I should create poco classes and how can map them.

[image]

[image]

And i have created the POCO classes as below.

```
public partial class ExpenseIncome
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ExpIncTypeID { get; set; }
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    public int? UserID { get; set; }
    public int? GroupID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AddedDate { get; set; }
    public string Explanation { get; set; }
    public int? ParentItemID { get; set; }
    public decimal? Balance { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ActivationDate { get; set; }
    // this is  navigation property
    public virtual ExpenseIncomeType ExpenseIncomeType { get; set; }
}
```

And other POCO is :

```
public partial class ExpenseIncomeType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TName { get; set; }
    public int? IsExpOrInc { get; set; }
    public int? ParentExpTypeID { get; set; }
    public decimal? ExpIncTypeDefaultAmount { get; set; }
    public string UserGroupUniqueValue { get; set; }
    public int? UserGroupID { get; set; }
    // this is  navigation property
    public virtual ExpenseIncome ExpenseIncome { get; set; }
}
```

So, I am confused about how I can map the these classes in `ModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method of `DbContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be a 1:1 association. Surely, "Many" `ExpenseIncome`s can share the same `ExpenseIncomeType`. So the mapping should be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseIncome>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.ExpenseIncomeType).WithMany();
```

And the property `public virtual ExpenseIncome ExpenseIncome { get; set; }` in `ExpenseIncomeType` should disappear.

It's semantically correct to say that an `ExpenseIncome` "has a" `ExpenseIncomeType`. The reverse doesn't make much sense, although *technically*, `ExpenseIncomeType` could have an `ICollection<ExpenseIncome>`.

Comment: Hi, @GertArnold i'v done  as you explained and it works correctly .  Also i'v added ForeingKey to the end of Code .  now mapping  looks like shown below.         

`.HasRequired(e => e.ExpenseIncomeType).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x=>x.ExpIncTypeID); `  

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going for Code First approach, there are 2 ways at least to do this.

1. in the DbContext you have to override the ModelCreating like you said and write for each entity something like:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
      { 
        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseIncome>().HasKey(e => e.ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseIncomeType>().HasKey(e => e.ID);
      }
```

2. Create a mapping class derived from EntityTypeConfiguration and in the constructor of that class indicate related mappings.

```
    public class ExpenseIncomeMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<ExpenseIncome>
    {
     public RoleConfiguration()
      {
        HasKey(e => e.ID);
        // etc.
      }
    }
```

And after this each mapping class should be added to context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ExpenseIncomeMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ExpenseIncomeTypeMap());
    }
```

Your Poco models in the DbContext should match exactly the database structure, in this case you will not need to generate any database migration.